# JavaScript Mixin function

Tags: javascript

The function skeleton is at the top of mixin.js.  It takes in a target object (o) and another object with properties to be mixed in (mixin).

You should return a Proxy object from this function.  Override the "get" trap so that:

1) If the object already has a property, the object's property is returned.

2) If the object does not have the property, it returns the property from the mixin object.

3) If the property is "__original", it returns the original object "o".  (This design provides a way to "unmix" a mixin.)

4) If none of the other cases hold, undefined should be returned as the result.

You should not make any changes to this file outside of the addMixin function definition.

This is what I have so far,

```
function addMixin(o, mixin) {

  let oldValue = {};
 return new Proxy(o, {
   get: function(target, property) {
       if(target.hasOwnProperty(property) === true) {
         return target[property];
       } else if (target.hasOwnProperty(property) === false) {
         oldValue[property] = target[property];
         return mixin[property];
       } else if (property === '__original') {
         return target[property] = oldValue[property];
       } else {
         return undefined;
       }
   }
 })
// A sample mixin.
let PlayableMixin = {
  // Plays a system bell 3 times
  play: function() {
    console.log("\u0007");
    console.log("\u0007");
    console.log("\u0007");
  },
  duration: 100,
};

function Song(name, performer, duration) {
  this.name = name;
  this.performer = performer;
  this.duration = duration;
}
Song.prototype = addMixin(Song.prototype, PlayableMixin);

Song.prototype.display = function() {
  console.log(`Now playing "${this.name}", by ${this.performer}. (${this.duration})`);
}

let s = new Song("Gun Street Girl", "Tom Waits", "4:17");
s.display();
s.play();

console.log(s.duration);

s = s.__original;

console.log(s.play);
```

Expected Output 
Now playing "Gun Street Girl", by Tom Waits. (4:17)

4:17
undefined

Gives me an error instead of printing undefined.

Comment: Expected Output: Now playing "Gun Street Girl", by Tom Waits. (4:17)



4:17
undefined  It gives me an error instead of printing undefined.

Comment: `target.hasOwnProperty(property)` will return either `true` or `false` so you have a bunch of `else if` and `else` logic that will never be hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need the if else chain.  return already breaks out of the function.  `__original` should be checked first, because it should return the original object regardless of whether it exists as a property or not; it is essentially a reserved symbol name for a computed property.
Your code is also missing a closing bracket.

```js
function addMixin(o, mixin) {

  let oldValue = {};
  return new Proxy(o, {
    get: function(target, property) {
      if (property === '__original') {
        return o;
      }
      if (target.hasOwnProperty(property) === true) {

        return target[property];
      } else if (target.hasOwnProperty(property) === false) {
        oldValue[property] = target[property];
        return mixin[property];
      } else {
        return undefined;
      }
    }
  })
}
// A sample mixin.
let PlayableMixin = {
  // Plays a system bell 3 times
  play: function() {
    console.log("\u0007");
    console.log("\u0007");
    console.log("\u0007");
  },
  duration: 100,
};

function Song(name, performer, duration) {
  this.name = name;
  this.performer = performer;
  this.duration = duration;
}
Song.prototype = addMixin(Song.prototype, PlayableMixin);

Song.prototype.display = function() {
  console.log(`Now playing "${this.name}", by ${this.performer}. (${this.duration})`);
}

let s = new Song("Gun Street Girl", "Tom Waits", "4:17");
s.display();
s.play();

console.log(s.duration);

s = s.__original;

console.log(s, s.play);
```

Just a side comment: I'd complain about the problem description.  The way declared conditions are listed almost seems like it was purposely set up to be confusing.  It's like one of those silly riddles where someone makes you repeat what they say and say something stupid about yourself.